# .htaccess and wordpress 301 redirect everyone not on the approved list of IP addresses?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a cleaner way to do this?
I'm interested in updating the file with a list via a script that will run periodically with allowed IP addresses.

the logic is:
        If {REMOTE_ADDR} = (1.2.3.4|2.3.4.5|3.4.5.6|192.168.0.0/24)
         do nothing
        Else
         Redirect them 301 to the current website.

I've tried the following test:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    # Redirect all except allowed IP
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.101$
    ReWriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^234\.567\.891\.011$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://Currentwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the redirect stuff to happen **before** your wordpress rules. Because wordpress routes everything to index.php, the request gets mangled before the redirect:

```
# Redirect all except allowed IP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.101$
ReWriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^234\.567\.891\.011$
RewriteRule (.*) http://currentwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to wrap it in an `<IfModule>` to ensure that `mod_rewrite` is loaded and use `RewriteEngine On` to make sure rewriting is active.

Comment: Thank you, I started this question because I had to figure out how to allow my team to access an old website while still redirecting it for everyone but us.